# how to check c standard library function source code in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm currently learning c and want to know how a standard library function is implemented e.g.

[image]

I `control click`ed on the `fgets` function and it took me to the function prototype declaration of `fgets` in `stdio.h` header file.

[image]

But I want to see how `fgets` is implemented, not its function prototype. Is there anyway to see its internal implementation?

Comment: google should be able to find an implementation for you. Typically, all you get with the compiler is the header file, and the library file, but not the source code.

Comment: with java standard library, if i right click on a function name, it will take me directly to the source code of that function, which is convenient. Is there anything similar with c? I understand that I can find implementation online, but just want to know if there is a way that it can be done in IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for some standard library implementations, such as `glibc`, are available online, and you can look up [its `fgets()` code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iofgets.c;h=68177dbe22d3a3463291c3f25cf7188cc9ad4af1;hb=refs/heads/master). But the source code isn't typically installed on a development PC unless you're building your own toolchain for some reason (e.g., a cross-compiler). In fact, portions of the source code are often written in assembly. Only the compiled object files are usually installed on development / target PCs. Therefore, your IDE doesn't have access to the source and can't show it to you. Other standard libraries like Microsoft's MSVCRT are proprietary and the source code is not available, only the compiled library. You can always disassemble that of course, but the output is not likely to be very useful to you.

In general most (not all!) C/C++ programmers treat standard library functions as black boxes and rely on good reference documentation to understand their behavior.

Comment: Hi TypelA, do you mind if I ask, do you have any recommendation on good c/c++ reference documentation? Which reference do you use the most when you want to check something?

Comment: @Thor [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is by far my favorite reference. It's community maintained but it's about [as close to the Standard(s)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:FAQ) as it gets while still being readable for everyday use.

Comment: @Thor ... and here's [its page on `fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) as a starting point.

Comment: thanks for helping out! Your recommendation will help me to go a long way! :)